# PHP - foreach not looping through entire table

Tags: php, foreach

So, using the [Latte](http://latte.nette.org) engine I can't seem to loop through every data row in my table. I can only get the first one and I've run out of ideas!

```
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id,title FROM table");

    $array = array();
    while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $array = $fetch;
    }

    $Template["listing"] = $array;
```

Template:

```
{foreach $listing as $item}
    {$item["title"]}}
{/foreach}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpliest solution is (if you don't need `$array` variable elsewhere):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id,title FROM table");

while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $Template["listing"][] = $fetch;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Interesting solution :) Worked like a charm. Will mark as correct whenever possible.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `$array = $fetch`, run `$array[] = $fetch`, in order to add more items.

What you're doing is overwrite the array in every loop.

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I've tried that already and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? You get the same results when you do this?

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer as it actually explains what OP is doing wrong.

Comment: @Andy Things are unfair, sometimes. But that's ok, the other guy solved his problem as well. Some people usually don't care what they did wrong, they only want things working.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT id,title FROM table");

$array = array();
while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $fetch;
}

$Template["listing"] = $array;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id,title FROM table");

$array = array();
while($fetch = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $array[] = $fetch;
}
$Template = $array;
```